# Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project (Version 17.9.5) causes Exception

Tags: msbuild, csproj

In a tool written with C# (.NET6) I want to access the project file (csproj) of another project (also .NET6).

For this I have referenced the NuGet package Microsoft.Build (17.9.5)

In this library there is the type Project that normally is able to  read The projects (csproj) file of the corresponding project.

Project p = new Project(path to project file);

Unfortunately, I always get the following exception.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor

at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.get_GlobalProjectCollection()

at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile)

at TestMsBuildApp.Program.Main() in d:\Dev\Experiments\WPFAnalyzer\TestMsBuildApp\Program.cs:line 18

**Question: What is wrong with this procedure?

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.420 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.314 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:

x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]

registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Does anyone have an idea?

I tried the following
1.I reinstalled the .NET SDK
2.Restarted Visual Studio
3.Restarted whole machine
3.I created a smal sample solution
4.I tried other classes like (ProjectCollecionInstance.LoadProjects)

Comment: Are you using the [Microsoft.Build.Locator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022) library?

Comment: Hi Jonathan,  thanks for your reply.
Yes I do, the first line of code in my main is MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()

Comment: @JonathanDodds
If a create the same situation with projects build against .NET 4.8 it works.